# MPI, C - Unable to correctly generate random numbers

Tags: c, mpi

Hi I am new to Stackoverflow.
I am using MPI in C. I am running 10 processes.

Each of my processes contains a random number generator that uniquely generates a random number (0 or 1) for that process.

However, when I run my code, I have found that processes with even numbered ranks (such as rank 0 or rank 2 or rank 4) are only assigned the random number 0. Only 0.
Meanwhile, processes with odd numbered ranks (such as rank 1 or rank 3 or rank 4) are only assigned the random number 1.

How do I modify my code such that some even-numbered processes can get assigned the random number 1 and some odd-numbered processes can get assigned the random number 0?

Here is my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    //try to generate unique random number 
    srand(time(NULL)+world_rank);
    int rando =  rand()%2;
    // Print off rank with random number
    printf("Rank %d has the random value %d\n", world_rank, rando);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Rank 0 has the random value 0
Rank 7 has the random value 1
Rank 8 has the random value 0
Rank 9 has the random value 1
Rank 1 has the random value 1
Rank 2 has the random value 0
Rank 4 has the random value 0
Rank 3 has the random value 1
Rank 5 has the random value 1
Rank 6 has the random value 0
```

Thank you

Comment: how many times did you run your program ? I tried with 4 MPI tasks and generally get different outputs between runs.

Comment: I tried the same amount as you.  
Did you get odd-numbered ranks having random values both 0 and 1?

Comment: yes I did. Which OS are you running on ?

Comment: Try running again and also report the return values of time and process ID independently.  This will provide greater insight to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is `time(NULL)+world_rank`.

Are these combined well?

---

All even process, of course have the least significant bit  of `world_rank` as 0 and odd ones 1, by definition.

For a given time of day, in seconds, the value from `time()` may be the same for each start of the process if started at about the same time.

We can be reasonable sure about the properties of `time()`: it increases, it is the same each second.

We do *not* know that the process identifier is independent from *time*.

---

A first step would be to report the *time* and *process ID*.

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
printf("time() %lld\n", (long long) t);
printf("process %d\n", world_rank);
```

Next, combine *time* and *process ID* in some fashion better than `+`.  Let us hash `world_rank` or `t` to insure values are not trivially unrelated.

Example: trivial [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

```
const unsigned m = 1664525u;
const unsigned c = 1013904223u;
unsigned t_hashed = (unsigned) t;
t_hashed = m*t_hashed + c;
```

Now combine:

```
srand(t_hashed ^ world_rank);
```

---

Should this not provide satisfactory results, other sources of numeric [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) are needed.

Comment: If the clocks are synchronized, `time(NULL)+world_rank` is different on all the MPI ranks. Maybe not ideal to have all the seeds in the same range, but that should never lead to 100% reproducible results. FWIW, I get random numbers in my environment (as long as I do not run more than one job per second)